# Let $R=\mathbb{R}[X, Y].$ Find a nonzero ideal $J \subset R$ that is prime but not maximal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know this is incorrect, but this is the furthest I've gone with the problem:

Let $J$ be the ideal that consists of $p(x, y) \in R$ such that each $p(x, y)$ is a finite sum of the form $ax^{e_1}y^{e_2}$ where $ a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $e_1, e_2 \geq 1$, and the 0 polynomial. That is, each term of $p(x, y)$ has both an $x$ and a $y$ in it, there are no terms of $p(x, y)$ that are just $ax^b$ or $ay^b$ for some integer b. We can verify that $J$ is an ideal of $R.$ For any $r \in R$ and $j \in J$ consider,  $jr$ and $rj.$ Because every term in j has both a power of $x$ and a power of $y,$ so will $jr$ and $rj.$ So $jr, rj \in J$ and $J$ is an ideal of $R$.

I can show that $J$ is not maximal, because it is contained in the ideal $I$ that consists of $f(x, y) \in R$ or degree larger than or equal to $2$, which is not equal to $J$ or $R.$

I know that it is not prime, since $(x+x^2)y \in J$ and neither of these are in $J.$ This is the problem I keep running into though, no matter what I try. I am having a very difficult time finding an ideal that is prime in this ring.

Comment: Hint: if $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$, the quotient $R/I$ is an integral domain (resp. a field) iff $R$ is prime (resp. maximal). Can you find an ideal to quotient by to obtain the integral domain (and non-field) $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

Comment: @csch2 So if you quotient by (y)?

Comment: Exactly. You can prove a more general isomorphism $R[x,y]/(y)\cong R[x]$ for $R$ an arbitrary commutative ring.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try!